# How to create cram bonds with anchors

Tags: chemfig

I want to recreate the chemical structure of [1,8-cineol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eucalyptol) in chemfig. On Wikipedia it's shown like this:

[image]

The best I can come up with is this code, with an anchor for the oxygen atom:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{*6(-(-[:-90](-[:-30])(-[:-150])(<[:110,1.8]O?))---?(-)--)}
\end{document}
```

This results in the following picture:

[image]

I have read chemfig's documentation about anchors, but I can't figure out how to make that second bond to the oxygen atom also a cram bond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the chemfig manual page 15:
[image]

Thusadding a name and bondtype to the hook (?) can be done:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{*6(-(-[:-90](-[:-30])(-[:-150])(<[:110,1.8]O?[a,4]))---?[a,4](-)--)}
\end{document}
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: It is also enough to add `[,{>}]` after the anchor.

Comment: @KessVargavind that works too, thanks for your useful addition.