# Hidden or background segment using chemfig package

Tags: backgrounds, chemfig, chemistry, resolution

In relation to this question [How to create cram bonds with anchors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/491449/how-to-create-cram-bonds-with-anchors), I wanted to put the segment in the background and the black triangle hiding it in the foreground.

[image]

How is this possible with `chemfig`?

Here there is my answer

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{
                   % 7
      -[:270,0.963]% 4
    -[:328.2,1.019]% 3
            -[:270]% 2
            -[:210]% 1
                      (
                -[:150]% 6
                 -[:90]% 5
         -[:31.8,1.019]% -> 4
                      )
    -[:267.9,1.001]% 8
                      (
                -[:210]% 10
                      )
                      (
                -[:330]% 11
                      )
    <[:102.9,1.696]O% 9
                      (
         >[:73.3,1.445]% -> 4
                      )
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Reading the [chemfig](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf) manual I have not found nothing.

**Edit:** Considering the output after the very nice comments, I have a white space below probably why I have not a straight line?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{
                   % 7
      -[:270,0.963]% 4
    -[:328.2,1.019]% 3
            -[:270]% 2
            -[:210]% 1
                      (
                -[:150]% 6
                 -[:90]% 5
         -[:31.8,1.019]% -> 4
                      )
    -[:267.9,1.001]% 8
                      (
                -[:210]% 10
                      )
                      (
                -[:330]% 11
                      )
    <[:102.9,1.696,,,,{preaction={draw=white,-,line width=2pt}}]O% 9
                      (
         >[:73.3,1.445]% -> 4
                      )
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Crossing bonds in chemfig](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40153/134144) might be interesting.

Comment: @leandriis Thank you very much for your precious comment....but there is always `tikz`?  :-( I wanted use only chemfig and just the moment I am not able to solve my question.

Comment: What about https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40164/134144? Probably you will have to adjust the width to prevent the white line covering part of the oxygen atom.

Comment: `chemfig` uses `tikz` so without `tikz` is not a good idea. In @leandriis link there are two answers, and if you use `<[:102.9,1.696,,,,{preaction={draw=white, -,line width=2pt}}]` for the `<` path it gets already close.

Comment: @leandriis Can you add an answer, please? I am not expert in chemistry..I am only 5 votes to vote up :-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I hope the cat didn't get mad and scratch me. :) ahahah. However you can put also your answer.

Comment: This is not an answer since it also overpaints something in the lower right where it should not.

Comment: Into my home are welcome also the cats :-) I am not able to put this code: `<[:102.9,1.696,,,,{preaction={draw=white, -,line width=2pt}}]`

Comment: Grazie! I am not an expert on chemfig but are you sure this is the optimal way to draw this diagram? (I am assuming that these quantities with the peculiar values are angles and distances, but as I said I have no clue so you can just ignore this comment.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I have adjust manually the  angles and distances with differents compilations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (with the construction to help the understanding):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{*6(-
    ([::150,0.75,,,draw=purple]-
    O?[Oxy]-
    [::162,0.75,,,preaction={draw=green,line width=8pt}])
    (-?[Oxy,{>},{red}]([::60]-)([::-60]-))---
    (?[Oxy,{>},{blue}])(-)--)}\qquad
\chemfig{*6(-([::150,0.75,,,draw=none]-
    O?[Oxy]-
    [::162,0.75,,,preaction={draw=white,line width=8pt}])
    (-?[Oxy,{>}]([::60]-)([::-60]-))---
    (?[Oxy,{>}])(-)--)}
\end{document}
```

The output:
[image: Molecule]

Comment: Thank you very very much (+1)...After can, please, you consider my edit to the question?

Comment: Replace `draw=white` by `draw=red` and you will see what's happening. That's the reason why I not using this work-around.